# Tag for electrocardiogram

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has tag [ecg-ekg-electrocardiogram](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecg-ekg-electrocardiogram) without any synonyms.

I propose that this tag be renamed [electrocardiogram](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrocardiogram) with synonyms [ecg](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecg) and [ekg](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ekg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented as suggested in the question.